# How to print deck of cards in human readable way using Python

Tags: python, class, repr

I am creating a deck of cards as a list and need to print out the deck. However, when I try to print the deck, it returns the object ID rather than something readable.

Note, the code here is incomplete. The Deck class should take in an input suit and return the cards 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, A for that suit. The default should return a full 52 card deck. However, I haven't figured out a way to make the default all of the suits yet. Currently the default is saved as spades as a placeholder.

I have tried using **str** and **repr** functions, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I am also not getting an error from my attempted implementation of **repr** function, so I assume that I am not messing up the syntax or anything.

```
from random import shuffle

# possible errors
class Error(Exception):
   """Base class for other exceptions"""
   pass
class RankError(Error):
    """Raised when input rank is not a valid card rank"""
    pass
class SuitError(Error):
   """Raised when input rank is not a valid card suit"""
   pass
class NoCardsError(Error):
    """Raised when deck does not have enough cards to deal"""
    pass

all_rank = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
all_suit = ["♠", "♥", "♦", "♣"] 
hand = []

class PlayingCard:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        if str(rank) not in all_rank:
            raise RankError("Invalid rank! Rank must be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, or A")
        if suit not in all_suit:
            raise SuitError("Invalid suit! Suit must be ♠, ♥, ♦, or ♣")
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rank) + " of " + str(self.suit)

class Deck:
    def __init__(self, suit = "♠"): # current default is spades, need to think of way to make default all the suits
        self.cards = [PlayingCard(rank, suit) for rank in all_rank]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%r of %r" % (self.rank, self.suit)

    def shuffle_deck():
        self.shuffled_cards = random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal_card(card_count):
        if card_count > len(cards):
            raise NoCardsError("Not enough cards in the deck to deal.")
        else:
            hand = hand.append(cards.pop())
            return hand


deck1 = Deck()
print(deck1.cards)
```

I expect a list output that looks like

[2 of ♠, 3 of ♠, 4 of ♠, 5 of ♠, 6 of ♠, etc.]

but the actual output is

[<**main**.PlayingCard object at 0x000001BE6C17EDD8>, <**main**.PlayingCard object at 0x000001BE6C17EB38>, <**main**.PlayingCard object at 0x000001BE6C17E748>, <**main**.PlayingCard object at 0x000001BE6C17E198>, <**main**.PlayingCard object at 0x000001BE6C17E400>, <**main**.PlayingCard object at 0x000001BE6C17E6A0>, <**main**.PlayingCard object at 0x000001BE6C17EE80>, <**main**.PlayingCard object at 0x000001BE6C17E470>, <**main**.PlayingCard object at 0x000001BE6C17E320>, <**main**.PlayingCard object at 0x000001BE6C17EEB8>, <**main**.PlayingCard object at 0x000001BE6C17E160>, <**main**.PlayingCard object at 0x000001BE6C17E358>, <**main**.PlayingCard object at 0x000001BE6C17EF98>]

Comment: Also just a tip for string formatting, `str.format` is generally more readable and better for maintainability than using the `%` operator. This exists in both python2 and python3. And on python3.6+, there's also f-strings, which IMO is even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To print uncover the weird object notation,** try putting the `__repr__` definition in the `PlayingCard` class

For example:

```py
class PlayingCard:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        if str(rank) not in all_rank:
            raise RankError("Invalid rank! Rank must be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, or A")
        if suit not in all_suit:
            raise SuitError("Invalid suit! Suit must be ♠, ♥, ♦, or ♣")
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rank) + " of " + str(self.suit)

    # ADDITION HERE
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%r of %r" % (self.rank, self.suit)
```

So running `print(deck1.cards)` will output

```
['2' of '♠', '3' of '♠', '4' of '♠', '5' of '♠', '6' of '♠', '7' of '♠', '8' of '♠', '9' of '♠', '10' of '♠', 'J' of '♠', 'Q' of '♠', 'K' of '♠', 'A' of '♠']
```

**To print the entire deck**, you'll need to update the `__init__` definition for the `Deck` class.

```py
def __init__(self, suit = all_suit):
    self.cards = [PlayingCard(rank, one_suit) for rank in all_rank
                                              for one_suit in suit]
```

Running `print(deck1.cards)` again, it'll print out the following.

```
['2' of '♠', '2' of '♥', '2' of '♦', '2' of '♣', '3' of '♠', '3' of '♥', '3' of '♦', '3' of '♣', '4' of '♠', '4' of '♥', '4' of '♦', '4' of '♣', '5' of '♠', '5' of '♥', '5' of '♦', '5' of '♣', '6' of '♠', '6' of '♥', '6' of '♦', '6' of '♣', '7' of '♠', '7' of '♥', '7' of '♦', '7' of '♣', '8' of '♠', '8' of '♥', '8' of '♦', '8' of '♣', '9' of '♠', '9' of '♥', '9' of '♦', '9' of '♣', '10' of '♠', '10' of '♥', '10' of '♦', '10' of '♣', 'J' of '♠', 'J' of '♥', 'J' of '♦', 'J' of '♣', 'Q' of '♠', 'Q' of '♥', 'Q' of '♦', 'Q' of '♣', 'K' of '♠', 'K' of '♥', 'K' of '♦', 'K' of '♣', 'A' of '♠', 'A' of '♥', 'A' of '♦', 'A' of '♣']
```

And to double check how many we have:

```py
print(len(deck1.cards))  # 52
```

Comment: Awesome that did it. Thanks! :)

Comment: @dumdum Great! Also, when you get a chance, it'll be great to accept my answer as well :) Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Accepted. 
As a follow on question, do you have any advice on how to set the default for deck to print out an entire deck of all 52 cards? The problem is at the top of the post, after the note.